# Formula field with objects of another model in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I need to have a formula field where objects of another model are available. For eg: a custom model may have fields containing values related to a particular partner. Now I need to be able to create a formula based on those values in the custom model, and the reason I can't use a compute field is because this formula should be something configurable. So I need to be able to either use object of the custom model or directly fields as part of the text in the formula field.

Thanks In Advance

Yaseen Shareef

Comment: What's a formula field ?

Comment: What I meant by formula field, is a normal text field where I can have a configurable formula using an object from another model

Comment: If you can't use compute fields, maybe you can use onchange to change the value of your formula field when another field is changed ? That way you can still edit your formula field.

Comment: What is the use case with this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I have mentioned above is the use case...

Comment: @YaseenShareef Your question is not clear. Can you include more details about what fields you are using and specifically what it needs to do? Include relevant code from the models and views.